# Refresh View Template CakePHP Event System

Tags: php, cakephp

my ask is about CakePHP event system, I want to know if is possible make a reactive view using CakePHP event system? One usage case is present a reactive dashboard about sales for instance.

When someone puts a new order, another screen (Dashboard) refresh it's contents

Best regards!

Comment: For that task you need socket.io  or  socketo.me ,...

Comment: Hi salines, yes this may be the only solution

Comment: you can try something like Pjax (used in Yii2).